# Having trouble to import new data in an existing table using Hue Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hue

When I'm loading new data in an existing table and then do `select count(1)` to get the total rows number loaded, I'm only getting the count of one HDFS file.

[image]

The rows number only represents the amount of one HDFS file.

To import the "new data" I'm clicking here:
[image]

Also, here the total count in MySQL:
[image]

And the total count in Hue Hadoop:
[image]

By the way, here the file browser:
[image]

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please share how are you loading the data and also que query.

Comment: @dbustosp ok! It's done.

Comment: So you are saying that when you do a "select count(*) from movie;" you are getting the row counts for only one file (roughly around 421/4), is that right? Could you please run a "describe formatted movie;" and show what is the output (make it as part of the question).

Comment: @dbustosp 421 row is the count for one file. I've put more info.

Comment: Make sure the location of your table is correctly set and in case you are using Impala to run the query, make sure you run 'invalidate metadata;' command.

Comment: @dbustosp I'm not sure what happened, but after to put 'invalidate metadata default.movie;' I'm getting total rows correct 1682.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171407/discussion-between-dbustosp-and-javier-munoz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
invalidate metadata default.movie;
```

Most probably you were using Impala as engine to retrieve the data and this command is to reload the metadata.

> By default, the cached metadata for all tables is flushed. If you
>   specify a table name, only the metadata for that one table is flushed.
>   Even for a single table, INVALIDATE METADATA is more expensive than
>   REFRESH, so prefer REFRESH in the common case where you add new data
>   files for an existing table.

If you want to go further, [check this out.](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_invalidate_metadata.html)